# Repeat contents of plone pages from a folder in viewlet

Tags: python, plone, zpt

I have created a viewlet which should show the editable part of plone pages within a folder. The result is entire structure of every page in this folder. I may be going wrong with the page template code. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

viewlet code and catalog search:

```
class MyViewlet(grok.Viewlet):
    grok.name('my-viewlet')
    grok.order(0)
    grok.context(Interface)
    grok.viewletmanager(IBelowContent)
    index=ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/templatefile.pt')


    def update(self):
        self.context = aq_inner(self.context)
        self.project = self.getProject()
        self.project_array = self.getProjectArray()

    @memoize
    def getProject(self):
        portal_catalog = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')
        site = self.context.portal_url.getPortalObject()
        folder_path = "/" . join(site.getPhysicalPath())
        folder_path += "/afolder"
        results = portal_catalog.searchResults({
                                                'portal_type':'Document',
                                                'path':{'query': folder_path,'depth': 1},
                                                'sort_on':'getObjPositionInParent'
                                                })
        project_array = processResults(results)
        if(project_array):
            return project_array[0]
        else:
            return False

    @memoize
    def getProjectArray(self):
        portal_catalog = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')
        portal_state = getMultiAdapter((self.context, self.request), name=u'plone_portal_state')
        site = portal_state.portal()
        folder_path = "/" . join(site.getPhysicalPath())
        folder_path += "/afolder"
        results = portal_catalog.searchResults({
                                                'portal_type':'Document',
                                                'path':{'query': folder_path,'depth': 1},
                                                'sort_on':'getObjPositionInParent'
                                                })
        project_array = processResults(results)
        if not project_array:
            return False
        for i in project_array:
            i['class']='';
        project_array[0]['class']='active'
        return project_array


    def render(self):
        return self.index()
```

templatefile.pt:

```
<tal:block
   tal:define="our_url context/@@plone_context_state/canonical_object_url;
               home_url context/@@plone_portal_state/portal_url;"
   tal:condition="python:our_url == home_url">
    <div id="previous-projects-viewlet" class="respond">
        <div id="projects">
            <div id="projects-container">
                <tal:block tal:repeat="project view/project_array">
                    <tal:block tal:define="iobject project/brain/getObject">
                        <div tal:attributes="id string:project-${repeat/project/index}; 
                                             class string:${project/class} project;"
                             tal:content="structure iobject"/>
                    </tal:block>    
                </tal:block>            
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</tal:block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mathias. The problem was in the template file, it's the defined variable /getText to render just the page contents.

`<tal:content="structure iobject/getText"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `folder_path = "/".join(site.getPhysicalPath())`

with

`"/".join(self.context.getPhysicalPath())`

You are using the site path, instead of the folder (current context) path for the catalog query.